# Help with graphing a piecewise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

What would be the graph and domain of this function?
My domain is $(- \infty, \infty)$. I am stuck on graphing $-2x$.

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
x+9 & \text{if }x<-3,\\
-2x & \text{if }|x|\leq 3,\\
-6 & \text{if }x>3.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: -2x is a linear function, just take two points,draw a line between those points, and extrapolate

Comment: You are probably intending to ask about the *range*, not the domain.

Comment: @chubakueno will it be overlapping -6?

Comment: @AndréNicolas its asking for the domain. Anyways, will the range be (- ∞, ∞)? what will I do if the domain is somthing like the domain of -2x?

Comment: The domain, as you say in your post, is all reals.

Comment: $g(3)=-6$ based on the second line.  It happens to be true that the formula given on the third line evaluates to $-6$ for $x=3$, but that need not be true.  This makes the function continuous.  But the poser could have defined $g(x)=10$ for $x \gt 3$  For a given value of $x$, you just look down the conditions until you find the one that applies (and it should be only one) and evaluate that one.

Comment: @AndréNicolas and other thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-2x$ is a straight line. Your domain for this line is $[-3,3]$. At $x=-3$, $-2x=6$. At $x=3,-2x=-6$. So draw a straight line between $(-3,6)$ and $(3,-6)$.